# jQuery $.get HTML code and XSS

Tags: xss, ajax, jquery

**JS code**

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
$.get("/api.php",{id:encodeURIComponent(id)}).done(function(data){
    $('<div>'+data+'</div>').appendTo('.parent');
});
```

**api.php:**

```
echo json_encode('<h1>Hi username!<h1><p>text</p>',JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP);
```

Returned HTML content is **not from a user.** It is already written in api.php

Is this query XSS vulnerable? I heard `html()` is evil. What about `appendTo()`?

Comment: Are you sure no part of the string is controlled by the user? Does it literally say "username", and not the actual username from the database?

Comment: @Anders Yes, that's just random text for example. In api.php I sanitize and use var id for `switch ($id)` in api.php. Only 1 var that I get from `data attr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not user controlled, then it's not vulnerable to XSS.

Someone somewhere must be able to inject script into `data` to make it vulnerable.

`appendTo` isn't a sink in itself, however if it's appending free text to the DOM in this case then it could make the page vulnerable *if* `data` contains user input (read user input to be anything outside the security domain of the app itself).

Comment: Thank you! How I can prevent bad code in data attr value? Is it enough to sanitize $GET in api.php?

And if I use **data-attr** or **input val** values only in JS Should I sanitize  them in JS? For example:
`var val = $(this).val();
$(.div).css("width", val+"px");`

Comment: you don't need to sanitize input _value_ or _style_ set by JS; the browser does that for you. you _do_ need to watch _arbitrary_ attributes set by JS, like `onclick` for example: `.attr("onclick", strXSS)`